# download large files from azure storage blob to angular client in secure way

Tags: angular, download, azure-storage

hello i try to find a way to download files from azure storage to angaular client that deploayed to web app in azure , till now the app is authenticate the users in fornt of AAD using msal and after authentication i get an id token , know i want that authenticated user will be able to download file from azure storage i configured roles to my users in my storage account using rbac but i don't know how to do secure connection to download the files from azure , do i need a server if though i need to download the files both at server side and client side?or maybe i can do it only in the client side? please help me to solve this problem ,
regards ,
gal

Comment: One way you could do it is setup a MinIO server as a proxy, but I think you only get read-only access to your buckets that way.   Then, making queries to MinIO would be easier from an Angular app.  https://docs.min.io/docs/javascript-client-api-reference.html    Not sure if that is the best way though.    Most people write a microservice probably.

Comment: @Jim Xu ,thank you very much its look exactly what i wanted ,i will try and update if succeded 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can directly download file in client with package `@azure/storage-blob`. Meanwhile, you have configured Azure AD auth in your angular application. You can use Azure AD auth to access Azure blob storage. But **please note that we need to assign special Azure RABC (Storage Blob Data Reader) role to the users if we use the way.** For more details, pleas refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad)

For example

1. Install sdk

```
npm install @azure/storage-blob @azure/core-http
```

2. Implement `TokenCredential` with token you required from msal

```
import {
  TokenCredential,
  GetTokenOptions,
  AccessToken,
} from '@azure/core-http';

export class MyCredential implements TokenCredential {
  private tokens: string;
  constructor(token: string) {
    this.tokens = token;
  }
  public async getToken(
    scopes: string | string[],
    options?: GetTokenOptions
  ): Promise<AccessToken> {
    var result = new MyToken(this.tokens);

    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
}

class MyToken implements AccessToken {
  token: string;
  expiresOnTimestamp: number;

  constructor(token: string) {
    this.token = token;
  }
}
```

3. Downalod

```
import { AuthResponse } from 'msal';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyCredential } from './MyCredential';
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-download',
  templateUrl: './download.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./download.component.css'],
})
export class DownloadComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private msalService: MsalService, private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  async download(data) {
    try {
      console.log(data);
      let tokenResponse: AuthResponse;
      if (this.msalService.getAccount()) {
        tokenResponse = await this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent({
          scopes: ['https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation'],
        });
      } else {
        tokenResponse = await this.msalService.acquireTokenPopup({
          scopes: ['https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation'],
        });
      }

      //console.log(tokenResponse.accessToken);
      var cer = new MyCredential(tokenResponse.accessToken);
      var client = new BlobServiceClient(
        'https://<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net/',
        cer
      );

      var ca = client.getContainerClient(data.container);
      var blob = ca.getBlobClient(data.fileName  );
var properties = await blob.getProperties();
      var result = await blob.download(0, properties.contentLength, {
        onProgress: (progress) => {
          console.log(`You have download ${progress.loadedBytes} bytes`);
        },
        maxRetryRequests：10
      });
      // it will return  browser Blob
      var fileBlob = await result.blobBody;
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileBlob);
      window.open(url);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]